# loop 100+ getJSON calls and call a another function when completely done

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to read a grid and take that data and call a $getJSON url.  The grid could have over 100 lines of data. The getJSON returns a list of comma separated values that I add to an array.  Once the loop is finished I take the array and process it for the duplicates.  I need to use the duplicates in another process.  I know that I can't determine the order of the data that is coming back but I need to know that all of the calls have been make.

```
            for (let i = 0; i < rowscount; i++){
              $.getJSON(
      "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmode=json&retmax=500&term=" +
      terms,
      function (data) {
        var pmids = data.esearchresult.idlist;
        var pmidlist = pmids.join();
        pmid_List.push(pmidlist);
        if (i == rowscount - 1) {
          // call the related function
        }            
      });
       }
```

I can't figure out how to be sure that the process has finished.  The call to the related function has been done early at times.

Answer (score 0):

Well if we keep track of how many have completed we can fire off the code when the last one is done.

```
let complete = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < rowscount; i++){
              $.getJSON(
      "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmode=json&retmax=500&term=" +
      terms,
      function (data) {
        var pmids = data.esearchresult.idlist;
        var pmidlist = pmids.join();
        pmid_List.push(pmidlist);
        complete += 1;
        if (complete == rowscount) {
          // call the related function
        }            
      });
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use fetch and Promise.all

```js
const link = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmode=json&retmax=500&term=";

Promise.all(Array.from({
  length: 3
}, () => fetch(link + 'foo').then(e => e.json()))).then(e => {
   //called when all requests are done      
   console.log(e);
})
```

Comment: Help me understand what you are saying.  I can see where if I call it one time this will work but I need to loop and call the link with different terms on the end over a hundred times.  How will I know that the last one was done?  Also what does you length: 3 relate to?

Comment: It's simply doing 3 requests. The Array.from() part is merely for demo... I don't know how you obtain the terms to search for - but in short simply loop them using .map() to an array returning fetch()... and put the resulting array in Promise.all @user1314159

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function getJson(url, i) {
    return $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        //var pmids = data.esearchresult.idlist;
        //var pmidlist = pmids.join();
        //pmid_List.push(pmidlist);   
        console.log('completed', i)
        return data;
    });
}

function run() {
    let promises = []

    for (let i = 0; i < rowscount; i++) {
        const terms = 'foot';
        const url = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmode=json&retmax=500&term=" + terms;
        promises.push(getJson(url, i));
    }

    return promises;
}

Promise.all(run()).then(() => console.log('All are completed'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where do I put Promise.all(run()).then(() => console.log('All are completed')); ?  If I put it all by itself my other functions start giving errors like items not referenced. I take the line out and my code runs fine